# NodeJs monorepo - How to deploy with dependent packages

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, monorepo, lerna

We're using Lerna to manage our monorepo. Locally everything is great because we are using `npx lerna bootstrap` to link all packages.

But when things get deployed, packages have to be deployed to out private NPM, otherwise docker fails with `npm ci`

So, of course lerna helps with `lerna publish` but the packages don't have the new versions installed. So we have some hacky bash script that solves for this.

It seems like there should be some "correct" way to handle this though, that doesn't require a hack bash script.

So to paint this picture.

Npm Package: API v1.0.0
Npm Package: myPackage v1.0.0

If you update myPackage and it's now at v1.0.1. In order for API to work, it needs to somehow get myPackage v1.0.1.

How are folks handling this today wrt to deploying shared deps in a monorepo?